# cluster by multiple linear regressions

Tags: regression, clustering

If I have an X and Y feature, can I cluster by what linear regression two populations fall on?

Consider:

[image: this]

In the pink is one regression. In the yellow is another. I know that these two lobes are indeed separate populations (these are biological cell types from an actual experiment). I thought K-means clustering would work but it does not as it does separate the regression.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import cluster

two_means = cluster.MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=2, tol=1)

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jwillis0720/stackoverflow/main/how_do_we_cluster/dataset.csv",
    index_col=0,
)
X = df.to_numpy()
two_means.fit(X)
c = list(map(lambda x: {1: "red", 0: "blue", 2: "yellow"}[x], two_means.labels_))
plt.scatter(df["x"], df["y"], color=c)
```

[image]

The best I have found is a Mixture Model with an tied variance:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import mixture

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jwillis0720/stackoverflow/main/how_do_we_cluster/dataset.csv",
    index_col=0,
)
gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=2, covariance_type="tied", random_state=4)
X = df.to_numpy()
gmm.fit(X)
c = list(map(lambda x: {1: "red", 0: "blue", 2: "yellow"}[x], gmm.predict(X)))
plt.scatter(df["x"], df["y"], color=c)
```

[image]

My question is...is this stupid? Am I missing the point of a regression? Is this even a thing? This is not a multiple linear regression but multiple linear regressions within the same feature space. Is that how the problem is described?

Comment: What you describe (two linear regressions for each population) isn't really an appropriate way to cluster points. However, it would seem to me that you'd need to know the classes ahead of time to make this work. It also looks like some points are floored at -4 (along the y-axis), so a GMM may not be appropriate straight out of the box. Would be worth clarifying: "I know that these two lobes are indeed separate populations" - so you do know the classes the points belong to already?

Comment: Yes thank you. Let me clarify. We know these are two separate populations of cells by how we sorted them in the experiment. However, it is very much a pain. We want to know if this X feature is an appropriate way to distinguish them without having to do the the sorting experiment. The feature in this case is "number of mutations" and the Y output is "strength of binding". In one case, as the number of mutations increase, the strength of binding increases (gets more negative) in a very predictable linear regression. In the other case it does not.

Comment: You could consider estimating a logistic regression based on the data you have. Then, for each new point you generate, you could estimate the probability it belongs to a certain cell population. More specifically, your model could be set up to predict the probability that an example belongs to cell group A. When this value is above 50% (for example), you could classify a cell as group A, otherwise group B.

Comment: In your cluster plots you only use the X variable. That's why the decision boundary between red and blue is a vertical line. Your question seems to be: Can I get the green decision boundary (in the first plot) by clustering on X. The answer to this question is "No" as many points in plot #1 have the same X but lie on a different side of the green line.